# Can I change the path of file to be uploaded in item adding event reciever?

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

I want to change the file path that is uploaded by user. What I am doing is user will upload a file and I am doing some changes to that file in itemadding event. So, for that I am creating another temporary file with the same content as the file. Now I want to upload the modified file. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to move a file to some folder in the event receiver?

Comment: @ECM4D No. I want to copy the file the user wants to upload and then make changes to the file and then upload the modified file(not the original one but the copied file) to the content database instead of the file specified by the user.

Comment: I think that you should work on the item added event. After that the item has been added, get the file, make your edit and update the item

Comment: @NkSp I can do that but I want to know the answer to my question that whether it is possible to change the file that actually gets uploaded

Comment: @ABeginner updated my anwser. An other solution is to add a new item (with new File and same metadata) and replace the one added before

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file in the itemAdded event:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  SPListItem item=properties.ListItem;

  SPFile file = item.File;
  //edit the file with your logic

  base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
  item.Update();
  base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```

You can also add a new Item with the same name and same metadata but with different File. (and replace the old one added before).

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    SPListItem itemOld=properties.ListItem;

    SPList list = itemOld.Parentlist;

    //add your modified file
    SPFile file = list.Add(itemOld["Name"], _byteArray, true);
    SPListItem itemNew = file.Item;

    //loop throw your item metadata
    itemNew["Title"] = itemOld["Title"];

    base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    itemNew.Update();
    base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
}
```